# How to install MySQL as a service with options

Tags: mysql, windows-services

I want to install the MySql service with the --old-passwords flag

Iv tried running this and various permutations of it, but cant get it to work.

```
"c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1\bin\mysqld-nt" --install MySQL -defaults-File="pathtofile" --old-passwords
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Starting MySQL as a Windows Service](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/windows-start-service.html) (3.x, 4.x):

> Before MySQL 4.0.2, no command-line arguments can be given following the --install option. MySQL 4.0.2 and up offers limited support for additional arguments:
>
> - You can specify a service name immediately following the --install option. The default service name is MySQL.
> - As of MySQL 4.0.3, if a service name is given, it can be followed by a single option. By convention, this should be --defaults-file=file_name to specify the name of an option file from which the server should read options when it starts.
>   The use of a single option other than --defaults-file is possible but discouraged. --defaults-file is more flexible because it enables you to specify multiple startup options for the server by placing them in the named option file.

For [5.x](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/windows-start-service.html), it seems to be the same.